# How to correctly interpret fixed effect in a GLMM with repeated measures data and quantify its effect

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, glmmtmb

I have dataframe of relative proportions of cell types, measured at 3 different timepoints in several individuals.
I want to write a model that primarily evaluates the effect of time, but also potential influences on the longitudinal development of a few other factors.

My approach so far would be to loop over every dependent variable and every possible metadata variable and evaluate the model:

```
model<-glmmTMB(formula = (cell_type1~ Age + metadata1 + (1|patient_id) , data =  data, family = beta_family(), na.action = na.omit, REML = FALSE))

car::Anova(model, test.statistic=c("Chisq"), type=c(2))
```

I have a hard time interpreting the results from this. For example, if i do get a significant p-value for both my cell type and my metadata variable, can i say that the effect of Age is significantly influenced by my metadata variable? If so , what is the best way to quantify this influence? The metadata variables are usually fixed for one individual and don't change over the observation period.
Unfortuantely, potential influencing variables on my time dependent effect include binary, catgeroical as well as continouus data.

What would be the best way to approach this problem?

Edit: Another approach which seems a little more sensible to me right now would be to calculate a baseline model (time~celltype) and compare it to another model time~celltype+metadata via a likelihood ratio test. However, I’d still be stuck at quantifying the effect of the metadata variable…

Comment: Why fit different models for each covariate instead of one big model?

Comment: *"I’d still be stuck at quantifying the effect of the metadata variable"* if you look at the coeffecient estimate of the `metadata` variable, that is the quantification of its effect in your model.

Comment: Does that mean I have an effect on the slope, the intercept or possibly both? If both, how would I evaluate the impact on the slope alone?

Comment: I'd recommend doing some reading about interpreting model coefficients. There's a lot of high quality stuff out there. But in short, yes - adding a new categorical feature to a model will result is separate intercept estimates for each categorical level and impact the "slope" estimates of other predictors. Or you can use interaction terms to get slope and intercept estimates at each categorical level. My favorite book on this is *Regression and Other Stories* by Vehtari, Gelman, & Hill.

Comment: Thank you! That helped me a lot already!